# how to do backbone.js UI testing

Tags: unit-testing, backbone.js, marionette, gui-testing, ui-testing

So I've created an require.js and backbone.js (actually marionette.js) application that basically is some sort of mobile app builder.

Now I want to create tests for it, basically testing this scenario:

- Navigate to an existing project, e.g site.com/build/1234

  - Drag a component, check if it is added correctly.
  - Change properties    of a component and see if they are updated    correctly. I.e: I've a    properties panel which lists the properties
    of the selected    component, than for example I've a property which 
    is a selectmenu and    changes the size (small, medium, large). I
    should be able to test    this.

Now I've been searching on google, however since there are so many testing frameworks, i'm not sure which one to pick and which one provides the functionalities I need.

Potentially PhantomJS seems to be something I could use, however please advice me with some specific information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to actually simulate clicks, look into selenium (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/)

If you just want to test that your Backbone components(views, controllers, etc) and templates are working correctly, you can use a js test runner such as Karma (http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html) to run your tests.  Sinon can mock out your ajax calls for you as well.  It can use PhantomJs as a rendering engine, so you can actually render your views, and use view.$() style DOM inspection to verify the output of your views.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look. I'm currently looking for simulation like a human would do, so i guess it's simulating clicks ^^